# Scala: Getting Any instead of List from if-else

Tags: scala

The following snippet fails at 'fields.size': "value size is not a member of Any". Why is 'fields' not of type 'List' (as I would expect)?

```
val condition = "a"
val fields =
    if (condition == "a") {
      List(1,2)
    } else if (condition == "b") {
      List(1,2,3)
    } else if (condition == "c") {
      List(1,2,3,4)
    }

  var g = 1
  while (g < fields.size) {
    //do something
    g = g + 1
  }
```

Comment: Please post the specific compiler error.

Comment: Added the compiler error: 'value size is not a member of Any'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need a default value even though the if condition for "a" is always true

I would suggest

```
val fields = condition match {
    case "a" => List(1,2)
    case "b" => List(1,2,3)
    case "c" => List(1,2,3,4)
    case _ => List.empty[Int]
}
```

You can even define the type of the `fields` for extra security, if you wanted

Answer (score 2):

Consider this: what if `condition` is equal to something other than "a", "b" or "c"? Then, none of the branches will execute, and therefore it can't be said that `fields` is of type `List`

Runnable ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/SF4jFcK/0 (code also below):

```
val condition = "a"
val fields =
    if (condition == "a") {
      List(1,2)
    } else if (condition == "b") {
      List(1,2,3)
    } else if (condition == "c") {
      List(1,2,3,4)
    } else {
      List()
    }

  var g = 1
  while (g < fields.size) {
    //do something
    g = g + 1
  }

println(g)
```

Comment: This is correct though, adding an extra 'catch all' else condition fixed it. Seems obvious in retrospect. Can you edit your answer to explicitly mention that solution?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the code for that particular solution.

Answer (score 2):

*Scala compiler* couldn't find a matching case when all of the *if expressions* fails. So for that case `Any` type is returned

Valid form is

```
val fields =
  if (condition == "a") {
    List(1,2)
  } else if (condition == "b") {
    List(1,2,3)
  } else if (condition == "c") {
    List(1,2,3,4)
  }else{
    List.empty[Int]
  }
```